# Two "Choice" buttons, using same methods

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, methods

So in my iPhone app I'm building, I have two buttons that are going to be designated for "Choice 1" and "Choice 2" for the users to select their date and time (for ex. to schedule an appointment).

Choice 1 has an ActionSheet to display the date, and is set to where when the user taps "Selected", it automatically goes to the other method I have which displays two times that are programmed in (As NSArray classes).

What my question is, I want to keep those two methods, but use a method called "button1Clicked" calling both, and do the same for "button2Clicked". Any ideas? I'll be more than willing to supply code that I have existing. Thanks!

I couldn't find this already answered but if someone knows if this is indeed answered on the site here can you supply a link? That would be appreciated!

Go easy please, I'm still a beginner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify your question. Are you asking how to write a method which contains calls to other methods? Or are you asking how to hook up a method to be called upon a button press? Or are you asking how to have both buttons call different methods, which methods then call the two first mentioned methods?

For one method to handle multiple buttons:

Approach A:

```
- (IBAction)onSomeClick:(id)sender {

    // return if sender is not a button
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        return;

    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    if(title == @"Choice 1")
        // call choice 1 methods here
    else if(title == @"Choice 2"
        // call choice 2 methods here
}
```

Approach B:

```
-(IBAction)onButtonPress:(id)sender{ 
     // if you have the logic for differentiating between 
     // the sender in the showActionSheet method, no need
     // for it here, just send the sender as the param
     [self showActionSheet:sender];         

     // call another method here also if appropriate
     // .. or as needed call it from within the showActionSheet method
}

// note how this does not need the IBAction return. This method doesn't need to be 
// hooked up via Interface Builder
-(void)showActionSheet:(id)sender{
     // here you can do your differentiation logic if you need it
}
```

Comment: @icnivad @nickweaver the existing methods that I have now are simple -(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender statements, with an if than statement to call the time picker after user chooses date. - (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
 
 NSString *title = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" : @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" ;
 UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
          initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", title, NSLocalizedString(@"Please Select A Date", @"")]
Starts it all, a -(void)actionSheet for Datepicker

Comment: here is the if statement inside the -(void) method:  if (buttonIndex == 0) {            
                [self showActionTime:nil];
                
                mssg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[times objectAtIndex:[timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
                NSLog(@"%@", [times objectAtIndex:[timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]);
                actint = 2;
                time1.text = mssg; 
                }

Comment: Do you want to call the same method "showActionSheet" from both buttons, and then internally determine more specifically what to do based on which button is the sender?

Comment: (sorry, that's not organized that well)

Comment: @icnivad That's the goal: for both buttons to use these two methods. More or less, yes.

Comment: @Macfan9000, I'm confused. For the sake of clarity, can you list what methods you have and identify which methods you want called by which buttons or methods?

Comment: @icnivad  I have two " - (IBAction)" methods, one called showActionSheet:(id)sender and the other "showActionTime:(id)sender" and those are what I'd like called by buttons that are named (within the .xib file) "Choice #1" and "Choice #2". I also suppose that now would be a great time to mention that for each "choice" I have it being displayed to a label for the user (one for each button)

Comment: @Macfan900, I've edited the code above. If I understand what you are trying to get, it should help.

Comment: @icnivad (Again, apologies for sounding a bit clueless and like a "Freshman" at objective-c) What I've got now is :    - (IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender {
   // return if sender is not a button
    if (![sender UIDatePicker:[UIButton class]])
        return;
    
    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    if(title == @"Choice 1");
        // call choice 1 methods here
    else if(title == @"Choice 2");
        // call choice 2 methods here
}    How would I insert the call for the methods? [actionSheet.self]; ? maybe you might be able to help too @robotwoods

Comment: @Macfan9000, so what you will do to call the actionSheet method is place the following statement:

[self showActionSheet:sender]; // this will call the method showActionSheet that is defined in this class, thus the reference to 'self'

Comment: so this is what I have: - (IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender {
   // return if sender is not a button
    if (![sender UIDatePicker:[UIButton class]])
        return;
    
    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    if(title == @"Choice #1")
        [self showActionSheet:sender];
    
    else if(title == @"Choice #2")
        // call choice 2 methods here
        [self showActionSheet:sender];
    [title release];
}  But whenever I go to actually have a go in the simulator, it immediately crashes when I go to tap the appropriate button. Any thoughts?     @icnivad

Comment: Where is says in the code: if(![sender UIDatePicker:[UIButton class]]); xcode gives a "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT" "

Comment: You can just pull out that 'if(![sender...]) statement. That was just a conditional to determine which button was calling the on1Clicked method. You don't need to do that here because you are passing the 'sender' as a parameter to the showActionSheet method. Since in both conditions (whether choice 1 or choice two button was pressed) you are calling the same method (showActionSheet), there is no need yet for that if/then logic. Just remove all that and simply have one line - [self showActionSheet:sender]; see if that compiles. Then we'll go to the next step...

Comment: Ah! Ok that makes sense, So I just have the single line [self showActionSheet:sender]; and it works without crashing or freezing. (Thanks for your help in advanced! )

Comment: Now would I make my - (IBAction)showActionSheeet:(id)sender into a -(void) statement? @icnivad

Comment: Yes, I would replace the IBAction with void just for clarity, but it should work fine either way. When I see that IBAction I know that method is going to be hooked up to some object in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

well, you can add a 'tag' property to each button, and then at the beginning of your first method, check the tag value of the sender so that you know which was clicked. That way you don't need to duplicate any code. Is that what you are trying to do, or did I misunderstand your goal?

Comment: Long story short, yes. I'd like to avoid duplicating code as much as possible (I thought I'd have to at first).

Comment: so then either of these answers should work for you. Mine uses the tag, the other uses the button title...

Comment: The tag property is a better choice in determining which control is the sender. Because if you decide to localized the app, the button text could be different based on the language. The tag property is an integer value you can set in IB.